# Кастомный QDateEdit виджет на PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Я пытаюсь создать виджет `QDateEdit` в *PyQt5* с таким же календарём, как на прикреплённом изображении.

Пожалуйста, подскажите мне, как это можно сделать? Я буду очень благодарен!

[[image: Скрин виджета]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqHkn.png)

Answer (score 1):

> **calendarPopup** : bool
>
> Это свойство содержит текущий режим отображения всплывающего окна календаря.
>
> Всплывающее окно календаря будет отображаться при нажатии кнопки со стрелкой. Это свойство действительно только при наличии допустимого формата отображения даты.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class DateEdit(QtWidgets.QDateEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent, calendarPopup=True)
        
        self._today_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("Today"))
        self._today_button.clicked.connect(self._update_today)
        self.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        self.setDisplayFormat('d MMM yyyy')
                
        self.calendarWidget().layout().addWidget(self._today_button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def _update_today(self):
        self._today_button.clearFocus()
        today = QtCore.QDate.currentDate()
        self.calendarWidget().setSelectedDate(today)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = DateEdit()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, но видимо я некорректно выразился. Я знаю как сделать всплывающий календарь. Мне нужно сделать его дизайн таким же, как на моём фото.